# What would you suggest as pattern for canceling subscriptions in useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Most of you have probably seen this React warning. Me too, and it is clear to my why React gives warns us about unmounting during a state update. But I'm trying to figure out what is the best React pattern prevent a possible memory leak.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. 
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. 
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

In my projects I'm using this boolean flag `didCancel` to let my data fetching logic know about the state of the component. If the component did unmount, the flag should be set to true which results in preventing to set the component state after the data fetching has been asynchronously resolved eventually.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;

    const fetchEvents = () => {
      fetch(url, settings)
        .then(res => {
          return res.json();
        })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          if (!didCancel) {
            setEvents(data.events);
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          if (!didCancel) {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        });
    };

    fetchEvents();

    return () => {
      didCancel = true;
    };
  }, []);
```

So eventhough this works, I just want to know what you guys are using as a pattern. What could be seen as best practice? Is there remarkable difference when fetching data, then when you're only updating state? Please let me know!

Comment: If the component is closed and `useEffect` runs the return function, would the `fetchEvents` function even be around? Do you get anything logging to console etc in fetchEvents after killing the component?

Comment: It only runs when it mounts.

Comment: Yes, I see that - what I am asking is related to async call in `fetchEvents()` if the component unmounts before that task completes, surely the handler in fetch event is never called?

Comment: The only thing I'm currently not running when the component unmounts before the fetch completes is `setEvents`. However I did read about using [cancellation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) in the axios docs (which I'm currently not using). Do you have experience with this?

Comment: yes your code is the basic pattern for async effects that update state (usually due to fetch).  Of course there are syntactic variations using async/await instead of then chains.  Eventually you'll move to helper hooks that implement the async pattern for you where you just provide the promise-generating function and "setState" code.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using `defer` from `rxjs` library for this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = defer(() =>
    fetch(url, settings).then(response => response.json())
  ).subscribe({
    next: ({ data }) => {
      setEvents(data.events);
    },
    error: () => {
      setLoading(false);
    },
    complete: () => {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  });

  return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, []);
```